# What is the meaning of Storage="RowStore" in Query Execution Plan?

Tags: sql-server-2014

Hi i am using SQL Server 2014 SP1, Where i see there is the difference in SQL Execution plan,at every Object i see,

> Storage="RowStore"

Can Somebody please help me to understand what it means and what will be the impact of it in Performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other possible value is `ColumnStore` which would indicate that the data comes from a columnstore index. This attribute is informational. It does not indicate any runtime performance information.

Comment: but though its added in the execution plan, if it is added there then it should be getting used by Query Optimizer.Also there is change in the Cardinality Estimation formula in SQL Server 2014 SP1.

Comment: What is the used of that value how internally it is getting used?

Comment: That value tells you the storage format that this particular index is stored in. Columnstore indexes behave completely differently from rowstores. Read about columnstores. This has nothing to do with Cardinality Estimation formula.